# How do I access the values of an iterable object, without iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, iterable

I am very new to programming, and especially Python, so thank you for bearing with my ignorance. When using a a function that creates an iterable object, such as csv.DictReader() or enumerate(), I seem to be unable to index into the individual pieces of that object without a for-loop. A for-loop will easily break the object up into individual list-like components, and then even break those components into smaller list-like components, but I can't figure out how to get to these items myself. I know I could use a for-loop and save each piece of the iteration in new variables, but it seems there must be a more direct route that I'm missing. What syntax is the loop using to index into these objects?

I've tried, with "reader = csv.DictReader(file.csv)", for example, to just "print(reader)" (which only gives the object's location in memory), or access "reader[0]" (getting an error that 'reader' is not subscriptable). If it's not subscriptable, then how is a for-loop breaking it apart? Creating the loop "for line in reader:    print(line)" gives exactly the data I'm looking for. I can even further break down 'line' using "for piece in line:    print(piece)" What, exactly, *are* 'line' and 'piece' then? They don't seem to be "reader[0]" or "line[0]", respectively. How can I index into this data without having the for-loop do it for me?

As a side note, I get the same type of problems trying to access a dictionary object without using the name of the key. If I'm creating a new dictionary with variably-named keys based on a user-provided file, then I can't give the program the key names in advance; but, likewise, I can't find a way to index into the dictionary sequentially, without these names. A for-loop, however, has no problem doing this. I can't imagine it just "knows" the exact names of the dictionary keys in advance, so what syntax is it using to index into them sequentially?

Thanks for the help. I've only found a few other questions here that seem connected to what I'm asking, but they seem to be asking for other, specific, languages, or to be prompting some higher-level discussion with reference to obscure modules and functions that I can't make sense of.

Comment: The objects you use do not support indexing. Thats it. You can iterate and  collect each line into a dict or list or whatever and work with it after iterating it. for huge files this might break due to memory constraints. Or you can use `pandas` or smth alike to work more comfortably with the data.

Comment: You seem to have multiple questions and problems and none of them are specificly targetted in this question. Please split/research your problems and try to ask 1 question at a time, prodive a [mre] so we can replicate it. bioling problems down to 1 problem and providing a [mre] makes it clear as to what your problem is and it might even help you find the solution yourself. Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different - the better it looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally when a function returns an iterator, if I want to access to the items generated by the iterator with indexes (random access) I convert the items returned by the iterator to a list if the number of items is not huge. Here is an example for a dictionary.

```
>>> my_dict = {"key1": 1, "key2": 2}

>>> # The following fails because iterators don't have random access
>>> my_dict.values()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable 

>>> # The following works and uses the wildcard syntax
>>> [*my_dict.values()]
[1, 2]
>>> [*my_dict.values()][0]
1

>>> # The following works and uses the list class to make the conversion
>>> list(my_dict.values()]
[1, 2]
>>> list(my_dict.values()][0]
1
```